# Should JWT refresh token and access token travel together?

Tags: security, jwt, single-page-application

I'm building a SPA and i needed to authenticate users, so i decided to use JWT tokens.
To secure them on the client instead of using browser localStorage or sessionStorage i used cookies with both *httpOnly* and secure *flags* enabled.

With this configuration access token and refresh tokens travels always together.

I'm wondering if this configuration is safe or not, because if the cookies are in some way intercepted from an attacker he has the ability to also regenerate access tokens, since he has the refresh token.

In conclusion, is it the right configuration or there is an alternative way to safe the tokens with cookies without make them travel together?

Or is there any good alternative to safe JWT tokens on a SPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right tracks according to [current best practices](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps). When using tokens stored in cookies, aim to follow these practices also:

- Encrypted cookies, eg with AES256-GCM
- SameSite=strict, to prevent malicious sites from sending the cookie via CSRF
- Use a path such as `/refresh` for the refresh token cookie, so that it is sent less often
- Use a client secret for the SPA client, via its backend for frontend, which would be unknown to an attacker
- Keep cookies small, ideally by issuing reference tokens to the SPA

Comment: How can i keep cookies small if JWT are of fixed size? Or am'I worng?

Comment: It is not essential. but if your provider supports it, issuing reference tokens (similar to UUIDs) results in smaller cookies. These are then [introspected](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-jwt-introspection-response-08#section-4) to get a JWT for the API.